# Как реализовать оптимальную расстановку расписания занятий в уч. заведении?

Tags: алгоритм

Есть задача - на основе данных о преподах, группах, предметах, количестве часов в неделю для каждого предмета расставить корректное расписание занятий, желательно, оптимальное (без окон у групп и преподов, желательно без перепадов времени (сегодня первая смена, завтра вторая), по возможности, чтобы не было такого, что у препода всего 1 пара в день). В какую сторону копать? Какие есть алгоритмы?

Comment: Нифига у вас алгоритмы... Самый простой способ – это брать готовое распсание, а потом свапать уроки. Например, в среду 1 урок свапаем с 4-м, зн. и у 1-го, и у 2-го, и у 3-го, и у <вставьте число сюда>-го классов нужно поменять 1-й и 4-й уроки. Так вы избежите коллизий. Ну а как расставить уроки в вашем случае я пока не знаю, если разберусь, напишу.

Comment: Не думаю что такое делается в учебных заведениях так как очень много параметров будет учитываться при распределений времени преподавателя - включая вышеперечисленные как основополагающие, а после утверждается и уточняется.

Comment: А какова **целевая функция**, как оценивать оптимальность решения?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *Успешность человеческих начинаний, как правило, обратно
>   пропорциональна предсказуемости их результата*. (с) Насим Талеб

Я довольно долго занимался составлением расписания в университете и мне есть что сказать на эту тему.

Первое, к сожалению, программы, которая составляет расписание в полностью автоматическом режим нет. С этим нужно просто смириться. Её нет не потому что это супер-мега сложная задача, а потому что это как раз рутина, которой никому не интересно заниматься, поскольку она не несёт больших экономических выгод. Тех, кого пугает перебор 51! вариантов (1.5511e+66) могут попробовать запустить такой цикл. У меня на (Xeon e5 2678 v3 + GTX 2060) весь процесс занимает 30 минут, поэтому говорить о вычислительной сложности, сейчас, при всём уважении, это просто смешно.

Второе, если Вам необходимо реальное расписание, а не решение теоретической задачи, то нужно иметь ввиду следующее - математически идеальное расписание на практике НЕ будет идеальным. Несколько раз на протяжении 7 лет мне удавалось составить идеальное расписание (в математическом смысле), но ни разу оно не оказалось практически идеальным. Объясню почему, преподавателю внезапно нужно отвести дочку на секцию не в 9 утра, а в 17:00 после школы, вот так изменились обстоятельства, другой сорвал спину на даче, теперь он ходит на процедуры и надо изменить время, третьему перестало быть удобно это время просто потому что... Кроме того, часто бывает такое, что нескольким людям удобно одно и тоже время, а это коллизия, которую можно разрешить только вручную.

Третье, Вы знаете, как преподаватель скажу, провести 3 пары + 2 пары с одним окном, это не тоже самое, что провести 5 пар подряд. То есть, конечно, я не за всех говорю, может кому-то и легче, но наличие окон иногда очень упрощает жизнь и снижает общую нагрузку.

> чтобы не было такого, что у препода всего 1 пара в день

Есть такое понятие в наших ВУЗах и не только, как ставка. Если человек работает на 0.25 ставки и курс не большой, то, возможно, что у него всего одна пара в неделю, что соответствует 1 паре в день. Так что это не повод останавливать или менять перебор вариантов.

> Идеального варианта не выйдет, но 10к - всяко больше чем сможет самый
>   крутой завуч

Самый крутой завуч (в ВУЗе обычно эту тему курирует зам. декана) сделает любой алгоритм в лёгкую. Люди, которые занимаются составлением расписаний по 15-20 лет делают за пару дней расписание, которое всех устраивает с минимальным числом правок, а из 10к вариантов он сразу видит какие есть смысл рассматривать, а какие нет, потом за пару правок всё становится на свои места.

**В сухом остатке у нас критерии идеального расписания следующие:**

1. Делается итеративным методом, то есть в первоначальный вариант
   вносятся правки;
2. Нужен удобный способ внесения изменений, которые всегда возникают;
3. Желательно быстро получить нулевую итерацию, которая не идеальна, но которую уже можно править;
4. Критерий того, что расписание идеальное - те, кто по нему занимается довольны или одинаковы недовольны, чтобы не было ни кому обидно (**это самый важный момент**).

Теперь двигаемся дальше. Часто бывает, что в силу разных обстоятельств получается удачное расписание, все довольны, всем удобно. Вот старались-старались использовали Nvidia Grid и получилось расписание просто супер. С тех пор прошло время, допустим два года, и вот было бы не плохо его снова использовать, но... Никто не знает где файл расписания или какой из вариантов тех файлов, которые есть правильный... Знающие товарищи меня поправят, что всё можно найти и восстановить, но расписание настолько "важная" и нудная штука, что на практике после того как расписание готово, обычно все делают вздох облегчения, а память стирает травмирующие воспоминания.

**В итоге имеем ещё два пункта:**

- Нужно хранить информацию о предыдущих удачных расписаниях и
  модифицировать хорошие (для Вашей конкретной организации) варианты.
- Нужен удобный визуальный редактор для изменения расписания.

*Из написанного выше напрашивается вывод, что лучше всего использовать нейросеть для решения данной задачи, а расписание хранить в XML-файле.*

Открытым остаётся вопрос - какую сеть использовать?

Поделюсь с Вами результатами моих изысканий. Лучше всего с этой задачей (я, конечно, перепробовал не все на свете виды сетей, поэтому "лучше всего" в "в рамках разумного") справляются LSTM-сети (сеть долгой краткосрочной памяти). Если интересно подробнее, то вот Вам целая [диссертация](http://www.felixgers.de/papers/phd.pdf) на эту тему.

Ещё один момент, если Вы, в отличие от меня, доведёте эту тему до конца и получите готовый продукт. Есть две наиболее популярные программы для составления расписаний. У нас это [АВТОРасписание](https://www.mmis.ru/programs/avtor), а у них это [aSc TimeTables](https://www.asctimetables.com). С ними имеет смысл ознакомится в любом случае, чтобы посмотреть на их "фишки" и недостатки.

Вот как-то так. Если будут вопросы - спрашивайте.

Удачи Вам в составлении расписаний!

Comment: подскажите, вычисления (про 30 минут) велись всеми ядрами процесора или одним ? или видеокартой ?

Comment: Так много слов а алгоритм только я здесь не увидел?

Comment: @Интик всеми ядрами и GPU. Спасибо, что спросили, важный момент - желательно приоритет процесса ставить высоким и реального времени и приоритет ввода/вывода - высокий

Comment: @IvaMuxa только Вы. Потому что: 
а) алгоритм по определению - конечная совокупность точно заданных правил решения произвольного класса задач или набор инструкций, описывающих порядок действий исполнителя для решения некоторой задачи. Я со своей подробно описал порядок действий.
б) Вот Вам описание с примерами LTSM-сети в Matlab: https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ug/long-short-term-memory-networks.html
С Вашей стороны, для готового проекта осталось только только подготовить базу расписаний, но тут, прошу прощения, но помочь не могу.

Answer (score 10):

Универсального алгоритма такого как решение квадратного уравнения не существует (иначе вы даже и не искали его). Это так называемая NP полная задача которая в общем случае решается полным перебором. Оптимального решения может и не существовать в силу множества параметров и переменных.

Но есть различные алгоритмы и методики которые могут дать приемлемый (компромиссный) результат.

1. Метод ветвей и границ
2. Жадные алгоритмы
3. Генетические алгоритмы

Конечно ответ можно расписать на несколько книг, учебников, методик, кандидатских или даже докторских диссертаций, но я повторюсь алгоритма решения этой задачи нет пока. На счёт экономической целесообразности, то она есть. Если кто нибудь даст точный алгоритм, не перебор, то можно сократить очень много ресурсов и рассписание можно будет составлять на лету в зависимости сложившихся параметров.

Comment: жадный алгоритм упирается на подборе последнего элемента, предусмотренный на этот случай "провал" к предыдущим элементам для замены упёрся в глубину рекурсии и примерно два раза из трёх выдаёт ошибку вместо результата.

Comment: Ну, проклятие Белмана никто не отменял.

Answer (score 0):

Подумываю над именно этой задачкой не первый год и последний раз пришел именно к перебору всевозможных сочетаний. Скажем 10к возможных комбинаций. Идеального варианта не выйдет, но 10к - всяко больше чем сможет самый крутой завуч (или кто там составляет расписание).

Так вот, после генерации массива комбинаций, каждому варианту нужно будет присвоить оценку скажем в 10к и дальше у каждого варианта уменьшать эту оценку, если он не соответствует какому-то требованию.

Итог - ТОП-3 лучших варианта расписания

P.S. за реализацию не брался, возможно когда нибудь попробую на досуге

Comment: слепой последовательный перебор всех возможных сочетаний невозможен для одной группы у которой 21 пара в неделю получается 51 миллиард миллиардов перестановок предметов. Посчитайте факториал 21 если не верите. Можно конечно уменьшить количество если отфильтровывать перестановки математики  в понедельник с математикой в среду

Comment: Почему-же, очень охотно верю. Я и не претендую на полный перебор, скорее выработать правила которым алгоритм будет следовать генерируя варианты: сколько часов у предметов, в каких кабинетах, что за преподаватели, а дальше рандомная расстановка предметов с приоритетом - физкультура последняя. Важно, чтобы набор вариантов был именно рандомным, а не последовательным, где 99.999% расписания такое-же как у предыдущего варианта. Из такого "мусора" уже можно будет делать выбор в пользу расписания с наименьшим числом окон для учеников/учетилей

Comment: я вас немного расстрою. Кроме сведений, которые вы перечислили в вопросе, которые уже сложно обработать, есть еще много факторов, таких как, например, совмещение у преподавателей, когда его нельзя просто так поставить в удобный по вашему расписанию день ну ни каким способом, или необходимость специализированной аудитории для занятий, у вас может быть большая территория и много зданий в учебном заведении и устраивать кросс на выживание преподавателям и студентам, ну такое. Из того что реально можно сделать хорошо - проверки расписания, составленного человеком по заданным критериям качества.

Comment: @rdorn Думаю, что huxahetu уже поставил точку в этой дискуссии, но все-же отвечу про автоматические проверки расписания. Сдается мне, что реализация такой проверки не многим легче генерации расписания: вам все равно придется иметь дело со всеми матрицами, интерфейсом пользователя и всем остальным. Это не то, что можно сделать лучше, это немного проще, а практической пользы и вовсе почти нет. Сигнатуры автоматической оценки расписаний принесут минимум пользы пользователю, но при генерации отсеят 90%+ плохих вариантов. В остальном я с вами абсолютно согласен

Answer (score -2):

Google Or tools имеет модуль CP-SAT. Я использую последнее время его на работе. Это оптимизатор для подобных задач, да и в целом constraint programming.

https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).